# Jquery set div with class and id value

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have such jquery code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.lol').each(function(index) {
      console.log("#"+$(this).attr("id"));
      $.ajax({ 
        url: "/articles/get_prices/nr="+$(this).attr("nr")+"&br="+$(this).attr("br")+"&type="+$(this).attr("type"), 
        type: "GET", 
        data: {},
        success: function(text)
        {
          $("#"+$(this).attr("id")).html(text);
        },
        error: function(){
          alert('Ошибка javascript');
        },
        dataType : "html"
      });
    });
  });
});
```

and such haml code

```
.box{:id => art.ART_ARTICLE_NR.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')}
```

method

```
def get_prices()
    nr = params[:nr]
    br = params[:br]
    type = params[:type]
    @pr = find_price(nr, br, type)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :partial=>"search_trees/price" }
    end
  end
```

i need to set this div jquery value, but it is all dynamic, so after page loads, it go to db, and via id (which is another for each box) set it a value.

Comment: can you post the action get_prices of your articles controller? you can't use "this" inside the response, since that's another context, you have to pass the id to the action. Also, can you explain what you want to do? errors? something?

Comment: @arieljuod  want to put ajax result in div (class box but id is dynamic), i'll get result, for example if i write $(".logo").html(text); i see how logo context is changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, your js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.lol').each(function() {
    url = "/articles/get_prices/nr="+$(this).attr("nr")+"&br="+$(this).attr("br")+"&type="+$(this).attr("type")+'&id='+$(this).attr('id');
    $.get(url,function(){},'script');
  })
})
```

(you do an ajax request with script datatype, so the response gets executed and you don't need to handle that by yourself)

your controller:

```
def get_prices()
  nr = params[:nr]
  br = params[:br]
  type = params[:type]
  @pr = find_price(nr, br, type)
  @id = params[:id]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :partial=>"search_trees/price" }
  end
end
```

(add the instance variable @id and render a js view since the ajax request is 'script' type)

your view (search_trees/price.js.erb, this is important that you submit a js file)

```
$("#<%= @id -%>").html(<%= javascript_escape(render(:partial => "search_trees/price.html")) -%>);
```

(render the html view and set the html of the div)

you might want to add some checks to do the alert if something goes wrong (like... you can't fine the @pr object), so you cover both cases:

in your view:

```
<%- if @pr.nil? -%>
  alert('Ошибка javascript');
<%- else -%>
  $("#<%= @id -%>").html(<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "search_trees/price.html")) -%>);
<%- end -%>
```

Comment: will try, but could you also write xemaple withot renderinf js ?

Comment: you have to render a js file or a json file, the thing is that you need two values: the id and the html content, you could render an html file with the id somewhere, but then you will have to parse the response html inside the success function to split the id and the html and that's not right (that's json for)

Comment: in chrome log's i see that it fetch's data, but it doesn't set if for div

Comment: please post your updated code, have you tried my code? do you have any error on the logs?

Comment: i tried yours... no errors, in log i see data, but it is not setting for div